# gnuplot: Can you set shell variables in a script and then later call them?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, variable, gnuplot

I want to be able to issue shell commands from a gnuplot script, such as setting a variable, but it appears that the `system` command spawns a new shell instance as opposed to issuing commands to the shell instance which is running the gnuplot script. See the following script where the first line allows assignment of `$foo`, but the second line cannot access that variable. In this case, `$foo` is assigned as an arbitrary string as opposed to a reference to the directory, hence the `\"`

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
system "export foo=\"$HOME/path/to/dir\";echo $foo"
system "echo $foo"
set datafile separator "\t"
#plot "`echo $foo`/bar.dat" using 2:3
plot "<( sed '5p' $foo/bar.dat )" using 2:3
```

Comment: This is the normal behavior of `system` in various programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: Each `system` command issues a brand new shell, so the variable set with `system "foo=bar"` is gone
when Gnuplot goes to the following line.

A very convenient approach in your case is to use [here-docs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings).

```
foo="$HOME/path/to/dir"

gnuplot -p<<EOF
set datafile separator "\t"
plot '<(sed "5p" "$foo"/bar.dat)'
EOF
```

Some notes about the script:

- `sed "5p" file` means that all the lines of the file will be plotted, but the 5th line
  will be duplicated. If you meant to only plot the 5th line, use `sed -n "5p" file`
- This calls Gnuplot but is still a shell script, therefore it is better to always [quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)
  (such as `"$foo"`) to prevent word splitting.

Comment: Thank you! The sed command was just to illustrate how this may be useful, I actually meant it to be `sed '5q'`. On a side note, the `<(  )` part is of the form of process substitution, but I think this may actually be a gnuplot construct in this case. Try replacing the shebang with `#!/bin/dash` (if installed) in your script and executing. Now try `sed "5p" <( cat "$foo"/bar.dat )` in each dash and bash and see what happens.

Comment: @T.ZackCrawford You are welcome! And you are quite right, that is not process substitution but inner workings of Gnuplot, as I have found in the [PDF manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html). It is so nice that here in Stack we also learn by answering!